# Excel: Count Unique Values with Critera

Tags: excel, unique, distinct, formula, criteria

I am trying to write a formula that will count unique values (both text and numbers) in a range that also has blank fields with a set of criteria.

Criteria:

1. Shipment Type = Specific Transport Type
2. Status Column = "Unplanned"
3. Despatch Month = Specific Month

This is very easy to execute with a pivot table. However I want to be able to write a formula instead, as I don't like the idea of having to refresh a pivot table every time new data is added.

Here is the formula I have written for Unplanned Shipping by Cost for Truck 2018-03 in cell I15:

=SUMIFS($F:$F,$C:$C,I$14,$A:$A,$H15,$B:$B,"Unplanned")

The same logic doesn't really apply when writing a =COUNTIFS formula to measure unique consignments as the unique values with blanks fields adds a layer of complexity.

[image: See Image]

Answer (score 1):

## to count the number of record where `D:D` is not blank:

write in cell I7 `=countIFS($D:$D,"<>"&"",$C:$C,I$6,$A:$A,$H7,$B:$B,"Unplanned")`

Comment: Not sure how this works this formula has too few arguments.

The initial part of the formula you have written says countif Consignment Number = Despatch Month which is not correct.

Comment: Sorry for missing criteria1.  I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks Paicheng for the revised formula! However this formula is counting all values that fit the criteria, not **unique values**, this formula should be returning 2 (not 4). This is the main issue I am having writing this formula.